# Recursive calculation of variable template value

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17

This is what I'm tying (and failing) to make work. The idea is that `count<N>` has to be equal to `N`. This is a simplified case of a more complex calculation, don't mind the apparent silliness of this code.

```
template <>
constexpr size_t count<0> = 0;

template <auto N>
constexpr size_t count = 1 + count<static_cast<size_t>(N) - 1>;

int main()
{
    return count<1>;
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
<source>:5:23: error: expected initializer before '<' token

 constexpr size_t count<0> = 0;
                       ^
```

If I swap the general case with the specialization, it also doesn't compile. Is it even doable with variable templates?

[Try it online](https://godbolt.org/z/oBMbnB)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the correct version of the code:

```
template <auto N>
constexpr size_t count = 1 + count<static_cast<size_t>(N) - 1>;

template <>
constexpr size_t count<static_cast<size_t>(0)> = 0;
```

Observe the following:

1. The primary template must be declared before any specializations. No exceptions.
2. The specializations `count<0>` and `count<static_cast<size_t>(0)>` are different because their arguments have different types. In your original code, where you provide an explicit specialization `count<0>`, this specialization is not used by the recursion that occurs in `count<1>` as specified in your primary template definition, which is why the infinite recursion occurs.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks a lot for the clear and to-the-point explanation!